# Car rental in Cuba

Tags: car-rentals, children, cuba

What prices can one expect for car rental in Cuba? On the Internet it seems ridiculously expensive, are there better deals locally? Is it possible to rent child car seats (and how much would it cost)? Are there any unusual things about car rental in Cuba?

Comment: By 'car seats' do you mean for children?

Comment: @DJClayworth, yes, these small seats for children

Comment: Also, renting a car may not be as easy as "find a rental office and pay for the car". I've tried three times in three different cities and three times i've failed: either no cars were available or the rental office was closed for unknown reason. Renting a private cab with a driver, even for a whole day, is a comparable expense. Plus you get to know local people a little better.

Comment: @qbik I always advise against foreigners driving in Cuba, if you run into an accident and someone gets hurt, you will get into a legal nightmare. In Cuba, you are guilty until **you** prove otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Rent-a-Car facilities in this time of the year prices starts from *$70* to *$150* or more, this depends on the car type, how many days etc. Price need to be confirmed in-place.

Refer to [transport-related information in Cuba](http://vararent.com/guides/transport-in-cuba-and-varadero).

I don't think car seats are available.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, car rental is expensive compared with USA. Generally the rentals start at 60 CUC ~ 70 USD per day with this car (Hyundai Atos 2009):

[image]

Plus the insurance is around 300 USD, returnable at the end of the contract if you don't have any issue.

There are others alternatives, like renting a car to a natural citizen. [In this link you can see the Cuban version of Craigslist](http://www.revolico.com/autos/alquiler/).